# Collecting Data from ethstats

Tags: transaction-propagation, ethstats

For a simulation, I'm interested in collecting some data about the ethereum network. Especially propagation time and block times (as seen on ethstats.net). Is there an API that I can use for this purpose or do I have to go the web-scrapping way?